# SSRS PowerShell Cannot Convert Argument

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

We have regionalized SSRS servers and I am attempting to create a PowerShell script that copies items from one SSRS server to others in order to keep them in sync. For some items this is problematic. An example is System Policies (Copying over system permissions).

Originally I tried:

```
#Reference source SSRS instance
$SourceServer = "Source Server Name"
$sourceServerUrl = "http://" + $SourceServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$SourceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $sourceServerUrl -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential

#Reference target SSRS instance
$DestinationServer = "Target Server Name"
$TargetServerUrl = "http://" + $DestinationServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$TargetProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $TargetServerUrl -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential


#Compare System Policies
$SourceSystemPolicies = $SourceProxy.GetSystemPolicies()
$TargetSystemPolicies = $TargetProxy.GetSystemPolicies()

If ($SourceSystemPolicies -ne $TargetSystemPolicies) {
    $TargetProxy.SetSystemPolicies($SourceSystemPolicies)
}
```

When I try to SetSystemPolicies on the new server I receive the error

```
Cannot convert argument "Policies", with value: "SSRS.ReportingService2010.Policy[]", for "SetSystemPolicies" to type "SSRS.ReportingService2010.Policy[]": "Cannot convert the "SSRS.ReportingService2010.Policy" value of type 
"SSRS.ReportingService2010.Policy" to type "SSRS.ReportingService2010.Policy"."
```

After looking up the issue I saw that it was a namespace issue with PowerShell attempting to use a default Namespace instead of the SSRS Namespace. I updated my code to create a custom Namespace which still did not work.

```
#Reference source SSRS instance
$SourceServer = "Source Server Name"
$sourceServerUrl = "http://" + $SourceServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$SourceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -NameSpace 'RS' -Uri $sourceServerUrl -UseDefaultCredential

#Reference target SSRS instance
$DestinationServer = "Target Server Name"
$TargetServerUrl = "http://" + $DestinationServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$TargetProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -NameSpace 'RS' -Uri $TargetServerUrl -UseDefaultCredential

#Compare System Policies
$SourceSystemPolicies = $SourceProxy.GetSystemPolicies()
$TargetSystemPolicies = $TargetProxy.GetSystemPolicies()
[RS.Policy[]] $SystemPolicyArray = @()

If ($SourceSystemPolicies -ne $TargetSystemPolicies) {
    $PolicyCounter = 0
    ForEach ($SourceSystemPolicy in $SourceSystemPolicies) {
        $SystemPolicyArray += New-Object RS.Policy
        $SystemPolicyArray[$PolicyCounter].GroupUserName = $SourceSystemPolicy.GroupUserName
        $SystemPolicyArray[$PolicyCounter].Roles = $SourceSystemPolicy.Roles
        $PolicyCounter += 1
    }

    $TargetProxy.SetSystemPolicies($SystemPolicyArray)
}
```

The new error is

```
Cannot convert argument "Policies", with value: "RS.Policy[]", for "SetSystemPolicies" to type "RS.Policy[]": "Cannot convert the "RS.Policy" value of type "RS.Policy" to type "RS.Policy"."
```

I have also tried dynamically creating the namespace with GetType().Namespace with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was automating this incorrectly. I was attempting to create a new object with the correct namespace and assign it the old object directly instead of assigning individual properties. Final solution was:

```
#Reference source SSRS instance
$SourceServer = "Source Server Name"
$sourceServerUrl = "http://" + $SourceServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$SourceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $sourceServerUrl -UseDefaultCredential
$SourceProxyType = $SourceProxy.GetType().Namespace
$SourcePolicyType = "{0}.Policy" -f $SourceProxyType
$SourceRoleType = "{0}.Role" -f $SourceProxyType
$SourcePropertyType = "{0}.Property" -f $SourceProxyType
$SourceItemReferenceType = "{0}.ItemReference" -f $SourceProxyType
$SourceDataSourceDefinitionType = "{0}.DataSourceDefinition" -f $SourceProxyType
$SourceItemReferenceType = "{0}.ItemReference" -f $SourceProxyType

#Reference target SSRS instance
$DestinationServer = "Target Server Name"
$TargetServerUrl = "http://" + $DestinationServer + "/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
$TargetProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $TargetServerUrl -UseDefaultCredential
$TargetProxyType = $TargetProxy.GetType().Namespace
$TargetPolicyType = "{0}.Policy" -f $TargetProxyType
$TargetRoleType = "{0}.Role" -f $TargetProxyType
$TargetPropertyType = "{0}.Property" -f $TargetProxyType
$TargetItemReferenceType = "{0}.ItemReference" -f $TargetProxyType
$TargetDataSourceDefinitionType = "{0}.DataSourceDefinition" -f $TargetProxyType

#Compare System Policies and push source if different
$NewSystemPolicies = @()
If ($SourceSystemPolicies -ne $TargetSystemPolicies) {
    ForEach ($SourceSystemPolicy in $SourceSystemPolicies) {
        $NewPolicy = New-Object ($TargetPolicyType)
        $NewPolicy.GroupUserName = $SourceSystemPolicy.GroupUserName
        $NewPolicy.Roles = @()
        ForEach ($SourceRole in $SourceSystemPolicy.Roles) {
            $NewRole = New-Object ($TargetRoleType)
            $NewRole.Description = $SourceRole.Description
            $NewRole.Name = $SourceRole.Name
            $NewPolicy.Roles += $NewRole
        }
        $NewSystemPolicies += $NewPolicy
    }
    $TargetProxy.SetSystemPolicies($NewSystemPolicies)
}
```